# Multiple terms in a HAVING query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `food` with two columns: `fruit` and `species`. Each species can have multiple rows with different values of `fruit`. I want to find all species that eat exactly 1 `fruit` and know the value of `fruit` for those species.

This query worked to find the species that eat only 1 kind of `fruit`:

```
select species
from food
group by species
having count(species) = '1'
```

Now I would like 2 columns, one `species` and the other the associated `fruit`. How do I query with multiple terms in the `having` argument? I tried:

```
select species, fruit
from food
group by species
having count(species) = '1'
```

But get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "food.fruit" must appear in the
GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select species, fruit
                                   ^
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please do not compare numbers with strings. `1` is a number `'1'` is a string value, not a number

Comment: Wouldn't it have to be `having count(fruit) = 1`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's pretty OK in SQL or at least PostgreSQL TBH, `'1'` is an unknown-typed literal. It's actually the _correct_ way to specify a `NUMERIC` literal, for example. Personally I prefer to be explicit and write `NUMERIC '1'`, but just `'1'` is OK too, the type is inferred from the operator and other argument. That's what'll happen if you use a bind parameter after all, unless you specify its type explicitly in the protocol message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
   select species, fruit
    from food
    where species in (select species
                      from food
                      group by species
                      having count(species) = 1)
```

Comment: Depending on the data, you might need `count(distinct species)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but I believe the following would work:

```
select species, max(fruit)
from food
group by species
having count(fruit) = 1
```

This way we select the "maximum" fruit for each species (in alphabetic order). But selecting the maximum of a set of size 1 just returns that element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one aggregate function to get your fruit (because you're not grouping by `fruit`). As you're looking for just ONE fruit, you can use the aggregate function `min` (or `max`, it doesn't matter), and get what you want. IThis is an example:

```
WITH food(fruit, species) AS
(
    VALUES 
    ('apple', 'apple eater 1'),
    ('apple', 'apple eater 2'),
    ('orange', 'only orange eater'),
    ('pear', 'only pear eater'),
    ('melon', 'lots of fruits eater'),
    ('watermelon', 'lots of fruits eater'),
    ('strawberry', 'lots of fruits eater'),
    ('strawberry', 'berry eater'),
    ('blueberry', 'berry eater')
)

SELECT
    species, min(fruit) AS fruit
FROM
    food
GROUP BY 
    species
HAVING
    count(species)=1
ORDER BY
    species ;
```